# Can't get endpoints' uuids or labels using jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

this is my first question ever on StackOverflow.

I am currently using jsPlumb in order to make a sort of diagram. Each node of the diagram can have several inputs and outputs, therefore I have labeled and put a uuid on each endpoint :

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("name of node",
{
    anchor : [0,0.75,-1,0],
    overlays : [ ["Label", {label : "name of input", uuid : "name of input", location : [3.5,0.5]}] ]
}, targetEndpointOptions);
```

Then I am trying to get either the label or the uuid of my endpoints with this function :

```
function getConnexions()
{
    var connected = jsPlumb.getConnections();
    $.each(connected, function(id, connection)
    {
        console.log(connection.source);
        console.log(connection.target);

        console.log(connection.endpoints[0].getUuid());

        $.each(connection.endpoints, function(id, endpoint)
        {
            console.log(endpoint.getLabel());
        })
    })
}
```

As you can see I have tried two different ways with both labels and uuids. But that doesn't work, I either get undefined or null in the console. Could someone help ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @user9674896. I generally edit first posts, but in your case - there was no need to do so. Greatly formatted 1st question. Welcome to StackOverflow and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed the uuid on the label rather than on the endpoint. If you're trying to put the uuid on the endpoint try:

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("name of node",
{
    anchor : [0,0.75,-1,0],
    uuid : "name of node",
    overlays : [ ["Label", {label : "name of input", location : [3.5,0.5]}] ]
}, targetEndpointOptions);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback, I think I figured out another way to do this. But this was indeed the problem, thanks a lot ! :)